# How to hide a the contents of a ColumnDefinition

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

I have a SL4 user control which uses a grid for it's layout. The grid is as follows:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="LayoutHeaderRow"    Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="LayoutSubHeaderRow" Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="LayoutContentRow"   Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="LayoutFooterRow"    Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

My question is how do I hide the LayoutSubHeaderRow and it's contents?

Thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added `x:Name` to row definitions but that is not much use to you because `RowDefinition` elements are not visual elements and do not end up in the visual tree.  Hence FindName can't find them.

Your xaml needs to look like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="Layout" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

You can use the ordinal position of desired row to pick it out of the `RowDefinitions` collection and manipulate it in code

```
    Layout.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(0);
```